# Selecting Posts of Users whom I am following

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two models:

```
public class UserProfile {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> Following { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public virtual UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

I want to select all of the posts of the users that the current user is following. It's basically like showing a feed of the posts of people you follow on social networking websites. How do I do this in linq? Im getting an error with this.

```
var following = CurrentUser.UserProfile.Following;
var posts = (from p in db.Posts
                      where following.Any(a=>a.Id == p.UserProfile.Id)
                      select new Post).ToList();
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Above Code-First code is missing something. Could you show the actual database diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the navigation properties to get the result:

```
var result=CurrentUser.UserProfile.Following.SelectMany(u=>u.Posts);
```

I think the problem is you because you are trying to project your query to an entity class (`Post`). In EF you can only project a query to an anonymous type or a DTO (custom class).

Another way to do it following your idea is doing this:

```
var following = CurrentUser.UserProfile.Following.Select(u=>u.Id);
var posts = (from p in db.Posts
                      where following.Contains(p.UserProfile.Id)
                      select p).ToList();
```

`Contains` extension method is translated to an `IN` in SQL